# Aggregation with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

We are saving player stats for each match in MongoDb.

```
{idPlayer: 27, idTeam: 6, matchId: 1, score: 90},
{idPlayer:38, idTeam: 9, matchId:1, score: 6}, 
{idPlayer:5, idTeam:8, matchId:2, score: 20}
```

We want to know how many matches a team has played:
We want result as:

```
{idTeam, sumMatches}

{idTeam: 8, sumMatches: 6}
{idTeam: 9, sumMatches: 4}
```

We are tryning with aggregations but we don't get this result.

Any idea how to aproach this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$idTeam",
      matches: {
        $addToSet: "$matchId"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      idTeam: "$_id",
      sumMatches: {
        $size: "$matches"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Yes!! Thanks a lot. That is exactly want we were trying

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)